# Shopify collection sort method not working

Tags: javascript, sorting, shopify

Shopify recommends using this code for making a "Sort By" drop down on their collection pages: https://gist.github.com/carolineschnapp/11352987

I am building a new theme with Shopify Slate and this code doesn't work for me. Fortunately, another developer has commented on this and supplied a better code. Here is the code:

```
document.querySelector('#sort-by').addEventListener('change', function() {
  const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  urlSearchParams.set(this.name, this.value);
  window.location = `?${urlSearchParams}`;
});
```

Unfortunately this didn't work off the get go due to it not adding "sort_by" to the search parameter. I adapted the second-last line of this code to look like this:

```
window.location = `?sort_by${urlSearchParams}`;
```

This worked, but whenever I tried to change the parameter, the page kept reloading and adding multiple "sort_by"'s to the URL *(ex. ?sort_bysort_by=price-descending&=title-ascending)*

Is there any way I can change this code so that "sort_by" only appears once in the URL?

Comment: check your `#sort-by` element to see if it has the name set, if not set to `sort_by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you swap `window.location.search` with:

```
window.location.search.indexOf("sort_by") > -1 
? window.location.search.replace(/sort_by/gi,"")
: window.location.search
```

so it becomes:

```
new URLSearchParams(
 window.location.search.indexOf("sort_by") > -1 
    ? window.location.search.replace(/sort_by/gi,"")
    : window.location.search
)
```

Comment: No problem. Just a small reminder, the urlSearchParams, as far as I remember is not supported on internet explorer, so you might need to resort parsing search parameters manually for that.